# Wpa supplicant suddenly stopped working

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, debian, wpa-supplicant

Recently my wireless stopped working on my Debian testing system. It just doesn't connect. The best I get (only after a reboot) is that it says it did connect, but failed to get IP address. But usually it just tries to connect, disconnects straight away, connects again etc. so it never manages to associate correctly.

I am sure it did work about a month ago, stopped working after recent upgrades from the repository.

Any ideas how to find the issue and fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schoolboy error: it turned out that I incidentally installed network-manager on the system and it interfered with my manual wpa_supplicant configuration. After removing it everything is back to normal!